# Time series modelling peaks for hydrology

Tags: time-series, arima, armax, hydrology

In your opinion/ based on your experience, what is the best time series model (AR,ARMA,ARMAX,ARIMAX,ARCH,GARCH, or others) that is able to better reproduce the peaks of a time series. And if so, could you please suggest me a R/matlab/phyton package to do so?
I'm dealing with an hydrological time series: predicting the discharge peaks is the most important thing when we are dealing with flood forecasting.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would some form of quantile regression be useful here (since it would allow you to model the extreme quantiles)?

Comment: Are you trying to predict the amount of peak discharge or the times of peak discharge?  Typically, none of the methods you mention are useful for either one, because (almost by definition) floods are exceptional events and the hydrologic behavior immediately before a flood differs greatly from baseline flow behavior.  How about fitting a hydrological model?